# Is there research into the phenomenon of "increased skill leading to decreased attention" for L2 learning, and what can a student do about it?

Tags: resource-request, l2-acquisition, learning-psychology

User phills at [chinese-forums.org](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/61869-listening-to-audiobooks/?do=findComment&comment=489310) describes their experience learning Chinese through listening to audiobooks:

> Paradoxically, I couldn't do these other things before when I was worse at the skill.  I had to focus 100%.  After I got better, so that I could focus < 100%, I actually did focus < 100%, making the process just as hard as before.  Lol.

I'm curious about this phenomenon: as the student's language skill increases, their attention decreases, so perhaps their performance doesn't show improvement.  I can certainly relate to this experience.  (It reminds me of [defensive driver courses leading to overconfidence](https://www.drive.com.au/news/defensive-driving-lessons-dont-make-roads-safer-20120411-1wq3w/), so maybe it's a psychological phenomenon.)

**Question**: Is there research into the phenomenon of "increased skill leading to decreased attention" for L2 learning, and what can a student do about it?